# ¿Cómo almacenar dato de JSON en una variable de jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Estoy haciendo POST con jQuery, mi formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form class="modal-content animate" id="formularioCotizacion" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="close-button">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('modform').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="grillaCotizacion1">
                    <div class="form-item">
                        <input type="text" id="nombre_cliente" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion" name="nombre_cliente">
                        <label for="precio">Nombre completo del cliente: </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-item">
                        <input type="text" id="telefono" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion" name="telefono">
                        <label for="total">Teléfono:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-item">
                        <input type="text" id="correo" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion" name="correo">
                        <label for="correo">correo:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grillaCotizacion2">
                    <div class="form-item">
                        <input type="text" id="direccion" autocomplete="off" required class="cotizacion" name="direccion">
                        <label for="direccion">dirección:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" name="submitCotizacion" class="btnSubmitCotizacion">terminar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Mi script de jQuery es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function (data) {
    // HACE SUBMIT
    $("#formularioCotizacion").on('submit', function (e) {
        var nombre_cliente = $('#nombre_cliente').val();
        var telefono = $('#telefono').val();
        var correo = $('#correo').val();
        var direccion = $('#direccion').val();
        
        e.preventDefault();
        //A continuación, envío estos valores para que 'registro_cotización.php' los reciba
        datos = { "nombre_cliente": nombre_cliente, "telefono": telefono, "correo": correo, "direccion": direccion};
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'registro_cotizacion.php',
            data: datos,
            success: function (resultado) {
                //Aquí quiero crear una variable para almacenarlo y enviarlo en la ventana nueva, pero no sé cómo
                //Hasta quí llegué, ya no sé qué hacer, solo puedo enviar el nombre_cliente, telefono, correo, direccion
                window.open("reporte_cotizacion.php?Paid="+ nombre_cliente, "_blank");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Algo ha fallado");
            }
        });        
        //return false;        
    });

});
```

Mi script de 'registro_cotizacion.php' es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require('cn/cnt.php');
function generador(){
    $fh = date("dis");
    $nram2 = mt_rand(1, 999);
    $idCmt = '';
    $id = $nram2 . $fh . $nram2;
    $id = $idCmt . '' . $id;
    $llave = 'CTZ' . str_shuffle($id);
    return $llave;
}

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_SESSION["sess_cotizacion"])) {
    $clave = generador();  //llama la función que está arriba
    $nombre_cliente = $_POST['nombre_cliente'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];

    $total = 0;
    $total_articulos = 0;

    $tabla_cotizacion = "
            INSERT INTO cotizacion(clave, nombre_cliente, telefono, correo, direccion, fecha_cot) 
            VALUES('" . $clave . "', '" . $nombre_cliente . "', '" . $telefono . "', '" . $correo . "', 
            '" . $direccion . "', now());                         
            ";


    $tabla_producto_cotizacion = "";
    foreach ($_SESSION["sess_cotizacion"] as $keys => $values) {
        $codigo_producto = $values['codigo_producto'];
        $cantidad = $values['cantidad_producto'];
        $descripcion = $values['descripcion_producto'];
        $factor = $values['factor_producto'];
        $contenido = $values['contenido_producto'];
        $precio_unitario = $values['precio_unitario'];
        $sub_total = number_format($values['cantidad_producto'] * $values["precio_unitario"], 2);

        $total = $total + ($values['cantidad_producto'] * $values["precio_unitario"]);
        $total_articulos = count($_SESSION["sess_cotizacion"]);

        $tabla_producto_cotizacion .= "
            INSERT INTO producto_cotizacion(clave, codigoProducto, cantidad, descripcion, factor, contenido, precio_unitario, sub_total) 
            VALUES(
            '" . $clave . "',
            '" . $values["codigo_producto"]    . "',
            '" . $values["cantidad_producto"]    . "',
            '" . $values["descripcion_producto"]    . "',
            '" . $values["factor_producto"]    . "',
            '" . $values["contenido_producto"]    . "',
            '" . $values["precio_unitario"]    . "',
            '" . $sub_total    . "');
            ";
    }
    
    $numeroCotizaion = "";
    if (mysqli_query($Oxi, $tabla_cotizacion)) {        
        //esta variable es la que quiero que se devuelva y se almacene en una variable de jQuery, pero no sé cómo
        $numeroCotizaion = mysqli_insert_id($ConexionBD); 
        
        mysqli_multi_query($Oxi, $tabla_producto_cotizacion);               
        unset($_SESSION["sess_cotizacion"]);
        session_destroy();                        
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => 0));
        die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($Oxi));        
    }
}

?>
```

¿Alguien podría orientarme por favor?
Estoy perdido.

Comment: En tu php prueba con `echo json_encode(array('lastId' => $numeroCotizaion));` antes del `} else {` y lo recoges con `console.log(resultado.lastId)` dentro del success, a ver si te funciona

Comment: Me da resultado de undefined

Comment: Perdona, lo hice rápido y escribí mal una variable en PHP, en un momento lo corrijo, y vemos qué resultado arroja

Comment: Me sigue dando como undefined

Comment: Pero, cuando solamente hago un console.log(resultado); //Me nuestra un objeto {"lastId":10}

Comment: Me marca el error de Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lastId')

Comment: Vale, vamos a intentar lo ultimo... prueba con esto:  `obj = JSON.parse(resultado);
console.log(obj.lastId)`

Comment: Ya funciona, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya me muestra el lastId

Comment: Ok, me alegro :-)  Acabo de publicar una respuesta completa con algo de explicaciones. Si esta respuesta satiface tu pregunta te ruego la aceptes para que tu pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente, gracias.

Comment: Tengo una duda si no es molestia, ¿por qué se pone esta línea debajo de sessiondestroy? echo json_encode(array('lastId' => $numeroCotizaion));

Comment: Da igual donde la pongas, el echo no se ejecutará hasta terminar el script, lo importante es ponerlo antes del else... lo he puesto ahi para no mezclar y que se vea como una cosa aparte que no tiene que ver con la sesion

Comment: Gracias por el dato, ya marqué tu respuesta como la solución

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por contribuir al buen funcionamiento del sitio :-)  Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución, validada por el OP (Original Poster) en los comentarios de la pregunta ha sido la siguiente:

1. En el PHP realizar esta modificación aquí:

```
        session_destroy();                        
    } else {
```

por esta:

```
        session_destroy();                        
        echo json_encode(array('lastId' => $numeroCotizaion));
    } else {
```

porque antes no estava devolviendo nada, y así dificilmente podria recuperar el dato en la respuesta esperada del ajax.

2. Y en el ajax modificar esto:

```javascript
success: function (resultado) {
                //Aquí quiero crear una variable para almacenarlo y enviarlo en la ventana nueva, pero no sé cómo
```

por esto:

```javascript
success: function (resultado) {
    obj = JSON.parse(resultado);
    console.log(obj.lastId)
```

donde recogemos el dato en formato *JSON* enviado desde el PHP y lo parseamos a   una variable denominada `obj` que, debido al contenido específico de este *JSON*, se transformará en un objeto, al cual podremos acceder mediante su propiedad `lastId` y mostrar en consola.